# Copio de respuesta sin aportar nada

Tags: discusión, respuesta, eliminación-de-respuestas

A veces he observado un cierto comportamiento, un usuario A hace una pregunta (buena o no), un usuario B da una respuesta un tanto completa, un usuario C copia la respuesta de B quitando partes, es decir haciéndola menos completa.

A veces, esta respuesta recibe incluso más positivos que la de B.

¿No os parece injusto y que deberíamos penalizar este comportamiento? ¿Deberíamos eliminar esta respuesta? A veces es la respuesta elegida incluso.

La dificultad viene en saber cuándo se ha publicado cada respuesta, saber cuál fue primero.

Comment: Es un tema que creo que ya ha sido tratado con anterioridad y tiene difícil solución. ¿Como propondrías tu solucionar el problema?

Comment: Como ya he apuntado en la pregunta, con negativos o solicitando la eliminación

Comment: El tema de eliminar supongo que será algo complicado (con poco que haya cambiado la respuesta). Ahora, si te da la sensación de que la a copiado o que ha hecho algo "feo" (moralmente) yo lo voto negativo (**pese a que no es un uso correcto de los votos**)

Comment: _La dificultad viene en saber cuándo se ha publicado cada respuesta, saber cuál fue primero_ Eso no es problema, pues si miras la línea de tiempo de la pregunta verás ordenadas las cosas que le han pasado, incluyendo las respuestas que ha recibido

Comment: Puedes aplicar ambas soluciones que propones sin problemas. Votar negativo es algo que puedes hacer sin problema. En cuanto a solicitar la eliminación...es un tema delicado.Por un lado, a veces la respuesta es tan inequívoca que dos usuarios pueden dar exactamente la misma. Por otro, no es un tema de quien respondió primero, dos usuarios pueden estar escribiendo la misma respuesta  y uno terminar antes.

Comment: @Pikoh, a veces hay dos horas de diferencia para 4 líneas de respuesta

Comment: Como digo, cada caso debería ser analizado individualmente. Pero como digo, eliminar una respuesta debería ser el ultimo recurso en mi opinión. Pero no es mi opinión la que cuenta, sino la de la comunidad

Comment: Yo comentaría en la respuesta "copiona" preguntando al autor si podría ampliar un poco más la respuesta teniendo en cuenta que ya hay una respuesta anterior con la misma información. En el peor de los casos, por lo menos llamas la atención a la gente que lee la pregunta para que valore más positivamente al que ha dado la respuesta con anterioridad, y en el mejor de los casos, a lo mejor el "copión" da una respuesta más elaborada que la primera o que aporte datos nuevos.

Comment: Podemos asegurar que copia la respuesta y no que solamente puso una respuesta similar? hay una linea de tiempo para ver eso.. y tambien hay que tener en cuenta que muchos usuarios empiezan una respuesta y solo la terminan mas tarde... hay que tener cuidado con eso.. y creo que no hay que eliminar respuestas porque si, salvo que sean copias flagrantes de otra...